# populate a 2nd filtering select based on the first - ZF and dojo

Tags: zend-framework, dojo

I have the response json string returned from the first FS(filteringSelect) with the contents of the second , but i can't make it load it. I've tried with store.clearOnClose , but it doesn't work , my javascript is valid. How do you do this ? 
Here is the code from my form with the 2 filteringSelects:

```
$category=new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect("category");
    $category->setLabel("Category");
    $category->setAttrib("id","category")
            ->setAttrib("onChange","
                                    var cat=dojo.query('#category ')[0].value;

                                   dojo.xhrPost({
                                            url: 'getsubcategories',
                                           handleAs: 'text',
                                           content: { category:cat } ,
                                            load: function(data, ioArgs) {
                                                      var store=subCatStore.store;
                                                      store.data=data;
                                                      store.close()
                                            },
                                           error: function(data,ioArgs) {
                                                   if(typeof data== 'error'){
                                                        console.warn('error');
                                                        console.log(ioArgs);
                                                     }
                                                 }


                                    });
                                   "
    );
    $category->setOptions(array(
        "autocomplete"=>false,
        "storeId"=>"category",
        "storeType"=>"dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore",
        "storeParams"=>array("url"=>"getcategories"),
        "dijitParams"=>array("searchAttr"=>"name")
                          )
                          )
            ->setRequired(true);
    $subCategory=new Zend_Dojo_Form_Element_FilteringSelect("subCategory");
    $subCategory->setLabel("Sub Category")
            ->setAttrib("id","subCategory");
    $subCategory->setOptions(array(
        "autocomplete"=>false,
        "storeId"=>"subCatStore",
        "jsId"=>"subCatStore",
        "storeType"=>"dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore",
        "storeParams"=>array("clearOnClose"=>true,"url"=>"getsubcategories"),
        "dijitParams"=>array("searchAttr"=>"name")))
            ->setRequired(true);
```

I've red on the net that this is the way to do it , get the element of the 2nd dropdown and 
passed it values when 1st changes. Am i Wrong ?
Tnx for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know about zf, but this is how we do in js :

```
new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
id: "country",
name: "country",
store: countryStore,
required: false,
onChange: function(country) {
    dijit.byId('state').query.countryId = country ;
},
searchAttr: "name"
},"country");
```

Comment: i am a bit new in the field of javascript , so i might ask a stupid a question. What does countryId stand for - is it like dijit.byId(countryId) ?

Comment: in my case countyId was a field in my stateStore. for example in my stateStore i have id:1,name:Texas,countryId:1 . ie when the country will change, the values listed in my states will be the states with the countryid =1